# Primary Key for record appearing in textbox where Control Source is not PK field

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm having a problem with an Access 2010 database where the Primary Key of a new record is also being added to a non-related field when I move to another control on the linked form.

My minimal database consists of a single table called `Teams`. There are four fields in the table:

```
+-----------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+
|     TeamID      | TeamName  | CostCode  |  SortOrder   |
+-----------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+
| AutoNumber (PK) | Text(255) | Text(255) | Long Integer |
+-----------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+
```

This table is linked by the `Record Source` to a form called `Edit_Teams`.
There are three controls on the form:

```
+-----------------+-------------+-----------+------------------------------------+
|    Control:     |   TextBox   |  TextBox  |              ComboBox              |
+-----------------+-------------+-----------+------------------------------------+
| Name:           | txtCostCode | txtTeamID | cmbTeamName                        |
| Control Source: | CostCode    | TeamID    | -                                  |
| Row Source:     | -           | -         | SELECT TeamID, TeamName FROM Teams |
+-----------------+-------------+-----------+------------------------------------+
```

The `combobox` is bound to column 1, Limit To List = Yes

The form has some code to keep the combobox in sync with the rest of the form when you move between records:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    If Not IsNull(Me.txtTeamID) Then
        Me.cmbTeamName.Requery
        Me.cmbTeamName = Me.txtTeamID
        If Me.cmbTeamName <> 0 Then
            'Some other code that adds stuff to a subform.
            Me.Refresh
        End If
    Else
        Me.cmbTeamName = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

The combobox has two events:

```
Private Sub cmbTeamName_AfterUpdate()
    If Me.cmbTeamName = "0" Then
        DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
    Else
        GoToBookmark Me, "TeamID", cmbTeamName
        If cmbTeamName <> 0 Then
            'Some other code that adds stuff to a subform.
            Me.Refresh
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

and

```
Private Sub cmbTeamName_NotInList(NewData As String, Response As Integer)
    With DoCmd
        .SetWarnings False
        If MsgBox("Add '" & NewData & "' as a new team?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes Then
            .RunSQL "INSERT INTO Teams(TeamName, CostCode, SortOrder) " & _
                    "VALUES ('" & NewData & "', Null," & DCount("TeamID", "Teams") + 1 & ")"
            Response = acDataErrAdded
            Me.cmbTeamName = Me.cmbTeamName.ItemData(0) 'Move to an item that exists so Requery doesn't fire NotInList.
            Me.Requery
            GoToBookmark Me, "TeamName", NewData
            Me.cmbTeamName.Requery
            Me.cmbTeamName = DLookup("TeamID", "Teams", "TeamName='" & TeamName & "'")
            Me.txtCostCode.SetFocus
        Else
            Response = acDataErrContinue
            Me.cmbTeamName.Undo
        End If
        .SetWarnings True
    End With
End Sub
```

There's also this which is used within the previous procedures:

```
Public Sub GoToBookmark(frm As Form, FieldName As String, FieldValue As String)

    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rst_Type As Long

    On Error GoTo ERR_HANDLE

    Set rst = frm.RecordsetClone

    FieldName = "[" & FieldName & "]"

    Select Case rst.Fields(FieldName).Type
        Case 4 'dbLong
            rst.FindFirst FieldName & "=" & FieldValue
        Case 10 'dbText
            rst.FindFirst FieldName & "='" & FieldValue & "'"
    End Select

    If Not (rst.BOF And rst.EOF) Then
        frm.Recordset.Bookmark = rst.Bookmark
    End If

    rst.Close

EXIT_PROC:

        Set rst = Nothing

        On Error GoTo 0
        Exit Sub

ERR_HANDLE:
        'Commented out so I don't have to post the DisplayError procedures.
        'DisplayError Err.Number, Err.Description, "mdl_GoToBookMark.GoToBookmark()"
        Resume EXIT_PROC

End Sub
```

**The problem:**
When I type a new team name into the combobox it asks whether I want to add it to the team list, it then adds the team and moves me to the CostCode textbox where I can type in a cost code if available.
If a cost code isn't available the control should remain blank, but when I move to another control or record (i.e the control loses the focus) then the Primary Key for that record appears in the CostCode textbox and is saved when I change records (losing focus just puts it in the textbox, it doesn't appear in the table until the record is saved).

Comment: Funky behavior. My suspicion is that doing all this stuff in the `NotInList` event procedure is a bit too much for Access. Note that `Me.Requery` also triggers `Form_Current()`, so I'd say both `Me.cmbTeamName` operations are superfluous. Can you upload a standalone sample database to a filehoster?

Comment: I'm glad it wasn't too much going on in the `NotInList` event.  That would've been a real pain to sort out.  I'm going to have another look at the `Me.Requery` though as it does seem a bit overkill having it either side of the `GoToBookMark` call even if the second one only requeries the control.  I'll let you know...

Comment: On the first look it does appear that I can remove the first requery and change the second to requery the whole form.  I'll have to check it hasn't broken anything else, but all looks good at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies in the following line:

`Response = acDataErrAdded`

This line triggers Access to set the field that has focus equal to the value you just added as soon as it loses focus. Because you change focus to a different field, you get this weird behaviour.

Change it for `Response = acDataErrContinue` (that basically tells Access to not care about what you entered, and lets you handle it yourself) and your code should behave as expected.

Comment: Thanks Erik.  That did the trick.  I can finally get rid of the last annoying bug that doesn't really affect the operation of the DB (the Cost Code is a much larger number than the PK so is obvious when it's the wrong number) Always something new to learn.