# Can't Edit any query based on more than one table

Tags: ms-access

Being working on Access for a couple of months now, so I'm quite new. Minor VBA knowledge and next to zero SQL knowledge. I have 2 tables in my database. One is Contract details and the other is individual deliveries for all contracts. I have made a query connecting the two with a simple join on contract numbers(the SQL statement is a simple SELECT fields, table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON contract no) and made a form from said query to enter or edit deliveries. My problem is that suddenly the query(and the form as a result) became read-only. And after some testing, every query I make that joins 2 tables is created as read-only. The database is quite simple, some filtering code on the buttons that open the forms and so on. Any advice is welcome.

Edit: As a newbie, most of the definitions are alien to me..so I created a small database example of my problem. Sorry for the trouble.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/tt0a68a8534d38s/Problem_recreation.accdb?dl=0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my query not updateable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24267398/why-is-my-query-not-updateable)

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth could be. If I understand his problem occurred in a more complex situation with two "INNER JOIN" and conditions, whilst mine is just a combination of 2 tables with no calculations at all. I am 99% sure that this particular query and form were working fine a while ago, but not a 100% as I have multiple data entry forms and only this one is based on a 2-table query.

Comment: Well, you're not providing us with any information why this won't be the solution to your problem. Please provide comprehensive information on what your setup is and why you think it will work according to the answer provided in that post. It sounds like you just have a relationship that isn't 1-1, so you will need to have adequate unique keys.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Sorry, I feel dumb but could you take a look at the file I attached in my question? I can understand very simple things about Access.

Comment: Sorry, but no. I have a strong rule against downloading Access databases for multiple reasons (see [this meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/4646)  for some reasons why it's a bad plan).

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45740404) for an example how to post a properly minimized question when working with complex ms-access problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24269023/5339178) answer, section "Recordsets Are Updateable Under Certain Conditions". Most likely you don't have relationships between joined tables

**UPDATE**

I checked your database. As explained in the mentioned answer, updateable query requires relationship between fields with primary key or unique index. Your fields `[Ctr No]` don't have unique index. Here is most typical solution:
[image]

Or you can use contract number as primary key:
[image]

But in this case it will work a little bit slower (search by numeric fields works faster) and you won't be able to edit contract number.

Comment: I repeat, I am quite new in access so the article is a little confusing. I'll try to add more info. The two tables have the "contact no" field in common and I created a relationship(the first kind, I think it is called "one-to-one"). On the query I use the "contract no" field, some fields from the first table(such as seller info) and some from the deliveries table(date,quantity,price, etc).No calculations,filters,totals,etc. This is used in 2 forms. The one is an overview with all the deliveries and the other is made for data entry. None is editable.

Comment: Also, I looked in the database relationships, the 2 tables are correctly connected on "contract no". I tried checking the "enforce referential integrity" option(don't know what it does but it was mentioned in the article) and got an error "No unique index found for the referenced field of the primary table". Both tables have an "ID" field set as Primary Key and indexed with no duplicates so I am completely lost.

Comment: There is your problem. A relationship that can be used for Joins must start on a Primary Key. So change `Deliveries.Ctr No` to `Contract_ID` and link `Contracts.ID` to this column in relationships. Then you can set referential integrity.